# GCM error on receive: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-manifest

I followed the instructions here to set up a client GCM app: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

I opted to use the standard GCM rather than the new Firebase Cloud Messaging, for now.

My app server is a node.js instance using node-gcm to send push notifications.

My app receives the notifications successfully, however prints out the following errors:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Here are the relevant bits of my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service
    android:name="com.example.myapp.gcm.GcmListener"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="com.example.myapp.gcm.InstanceIDListener"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name="com.example.myapp.gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
         android:exported="false" />
```

My project has all of the above classes (minus GcmReceiver which is provided by Google).

GcmReceiver extends GcmListenerService
InstanceIDListener extends InstanceIDListenerService
RegistrationIntentService extends IntentService

Am I missing anything that might be causing this error? Does the error actually affect anything?

Comment: I tried out Google's own GCM sample app and I get the same error. I decided to migrate over to FCM and I no longer get any errors.

Comment: Using OPF Push library - same errors. I can't even handle onMessage callback.

Comment: Almost the same for me. I am using FCM and getting push notifications with these error logs. Do I have to care about them?

Comment: I have the same issue, don't know how to handle it.